# Creating a sequence Sum from the database

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

Hello all Well What i'm trying to make a sequence output , i need a value to be added every month which will be taking from my database , so what i want is the value to be added from all the the input data for the same month and then add it to a value(a) , then the next month(b) + this value(a) tell the last month , i know it sound confusing but  i will try to answer any question to explain more i hope i can get a help ... 
i will write what i was thinking to make in stored procedure :

```
SELECT * FROM mysqldatabase.usecases
A = Sum Work Where SingOffDate <='2017-01-30' and SingOffDate  >= '2017-01-01' , B = Sum Work sum A  Where SingOffDate <='2017-02-30' and SingOffDate  >= '2017-02-01',
C = Sum Work sum B  Where SingOffDate <='2017-03-30' and SingOffDate  >= '2017-03-01', D = Sum Work sum C  Where SingOffDate <='2017-04-30' and SingOffDate  >= '2017-04-01';
```

So i want to calculate The Work sequence evey month 
Lets say the Data From The efficiency table look like :

```
    Work | SingOffDate
    2    | 11/01/2017
    0.12 | 12/01/2017
    0.3  | 5/01/2017 
    0.48 | 11/02/2017
    1    | 15/02/2017
    0.86 | 09/03/207
```

And The reselt i want to look like :

> A = sum jan , b= a sum feb , c= b sum may ======> A = 2.42 , b = 3.9 , c= 4.76

Comment: This looks like a simple sum with a group by on year and month. It would help clarify if you could add sample data and expected result to your question - as text or in sqlfiddle.

Comment: @P.Salmon i will add sample of the data and the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear on your expected result but this may do

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(Work decimal(10,2) ,SingOffDate date);
insert into t values
 (   2    , str_to_date('11/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y')),
 (   0.12 , str_to_date('12/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y')),
 (   0.3  , str_to_date('5/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y')), 
 (   0.48 , str_to_date('11/02/2017','%d/%m/%Y')),
 (   1    , str_to_date('15/02/2017','%d/%m/%Y')),
 (   0.86 , str_to_date('09/03/2017','%d/%m/%Y'));

select max(case when yyyymm = '2017/1' then RunningTotal else 0 end) as a,
         max(case when yyyymm = '2017/2' then RunningTotal else 0 end) as b,
         max(case when yyyymm = '2017/3' then RunningTotal else 0 end) as c
from
(
select yyyymm,work,@rt:=@rt + work as RunningTotal
from
(
select concat(year(singoffdate),'/',month(singoffdate)) yyyymm,
            sum(work) as work
from t
group by concat(year(singoffdate),'/',month(singoffdate))
) t, (select @rt:=0) r
) u
;
```

Where in the innermost query I am summing the work by month and year, outside that I work out a running total and finally I use conditional aggregation to pivot the result which looks like this.

```
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| 2.42 |  3.9 | 4.76 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or maybe you just want the running total in this form

```
+--------+------+--------------+
| yyyymm | work | RunningTotal |
+--------+------+--------------+
| 2017/1 | 2.42 |         2.42 |
| 2017/2 | 1.48 |          3.9 |
| 2017/3 | 0.86 |         4.76 |
+--------+------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In which case use this query

```
select yyyymm,work,@rt:=@rt + work as RunningTotal
from
(
select concat(year(singoffdate),'/',month(singoffdate)) yyyymm,
            sum(work) as work
from t
group by concat(year(singoffdate),'/',month(singoffdate))
) t, (select @rt:=0) r
```